# DigitalOcean uploading simple php file - didn't send any data error

Tags: php, apache2, port, digital-ocean

I have a digital ocean droplet to which I want to upload a simple index.php file. I moved the php file to `/var/www/html/newtest` where newtest is a folder I made.

And then I made a `test.conf` file with the following code:

```
Listen ***.***.***.***:8009
<VirtualHost ***.***.***.***:8009>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/newtest/index.php"
    <Directory /var/www/html/newtest>
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow, deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**I didn't edit any other file on the server**

When I visit `***.***.***.***:8009` I get:

> The < ip-address-here > page isn’t working
>
> < ip-address-here > didn’t send any data